# Multiple values in case statement used as right operand of where clause sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I need your assistance in solving an issue, I did some googling on the same but could not manage to find a concrete answer. We have a job running from monday to friday, uptil now when run on a monday we used to get the report for friday and for all other days the report was generated for the prior day. This behaviour was achieved using the below query, the field selection is arbitrary:

```
    select field1, field2... from table where date = (
       case when TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate), 'DY') = 'MON' then TRUNC(sysdate - 3)        
           else (TRUNC(sysdate-1)) END);
```

Now the requirement has changed and we need to display the result for all three days friday, saturday and sunday when run on a monday.

I am unable to get a way to get this done. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` _expressions_ in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it should be enough to change `=` sign to `>=` in the condition and add another one to exclude the current date:

```
select field1, field2... from table 
 where date >= (
       case when TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate), 'DY') = 'MON' then TRUNC(sysdate - 3)        
           else (TRUNC(sysdate-1)) END)
   and date < TRUNC(sysdate);
```

Comment: ok that seems to fit the logic, let me give it a try and see if it gets my job done. this surely appears to be answer which will get accepted. thanks for the quick turn around!

Comment: the logic seems to work the only changeI have done is the last part which is instead of "and date <> TRUNC(sysdate) " I have used " and date < TRUNC(sysdate)" as I could also have date which are greater then current date and its not the records we want to fetch!!!

Comment: @SurajKumar OK, I corrected. I didn't think about future dates, you are right.